# Squid - SSL Falls from time to time

Tags: ssl, openssl, squid

We have a squid acting as a proxy to another server (both connections are secured). Normally, it works perfectly, however every few days our customers get a "Failed to establish a secure connection to ..." "(71) Protocol error" page. Only restart helps.

Looking into cache.log, I can see an increasing burst of the following message (starting with 3-4 messages, working fine for a minute, then another 10 or so, working fine, and then a full burst):

```
fwdNegotiateSSL: Error negotiating SSL connection on FD 15: error:1408C095:SSL     routines:SSL3_GET_FINISHED:digest check failed (1/0/0)
TCP connection to xxx.xxx.com/443 failed
fwdNegotiateSSL: Error negotiating SSL connection on FD 15: error:1408F119:SSL     routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac (1/-1/0)
```

Anyone encountered this problem? Know how to solve? Know how to recreate easily?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone encountered this problem? Know how to solve? Know how to recreate easily?

Based on the frequency, it sounds like a transient hardware or network error. Is the equipment failing or the line dirty? I have seen both in the past, and the telecom fixed both. For the equipment failing, they ended up replacing their NID. For the dirty line, a Bit Error Rate Test (BERT) detected a dirty line. I think they gave us some new copper in the physical plant. I've also seen Braodcom cards fail on Dell servers in mysterious ways.